# Group Install "GNOME Desktop"

Tags: puppet, yum

Puppet Version: 3.8.7

I have been working on building some system monitoring boxes and have ran into an issue when it comes to installing group yum packages. The normal course of installing packages of course isn't working but I figured that I would at least be able to work around this by including an exec to run the install as a command (like below):

```
exec { "GNOME Desktop":
        command => "/usr/bin/yum -y groups install 'GNOME Desktop'",
        timeout => 600,
     }
```

There is an available module on the [puppet forge](https://forge.puppet.com/simp/gnome) that seems to do what I want but it's not compatible with our version of puppet and we are not in a place to upgrade at this time.

I also tried the setup that was listed in the below server fault question but it also did not work for me:

https://serverfault.com/questions/127460/how-do-i-install-a-yum-package-group-with-puppet

I have also manually been able to run the following command but when I exec it as a puppet command, it fails:

/usr/bin/yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"

Why is this? I assumed that puppet is just issuing the command in the exact same way the terminal would?

Comment: What, *specifically*, does "it fails" mean?  The Puppet output should provide some details about the nature of the failure, and even more so if you enable `--verbose` output.

Comment: If I were to venture a guess, however, it would be that the command is timing out.  Yum commands that install many packages can easily run for more than ten minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the time out (or removing it) had zero effect, the issue is with the version of puppet and the ability to install group packages. I ended up installing the desktop environment in my kickstart file and ran puppet for everything else.